# 502 Bad Gateway on Ubuntu 14.04 with Nginx 1.6.2 and PHP 5.6.4

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway response on scripts that takes **longer than 5 minutes**.

The server runs on Ubuntu 14.04 with Nginx 1.6.2 and PHP 5.6.4

I'v created a test function, which fails:

```
    public function test(){
        sleep(600);
    }
```

I'v tried changing the fastcgi params, with no change.

**Config:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.xxxx.xx;
    root /home/forge/xxxx.xx/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/xxxx.xx-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "newrelic.appname=xxxx.xx";
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

}
```

nginx.conf http block (The part I'v changed):

```
http {
    fastcgi_buffers 32 32k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    # EDIT: Added and tried these:
    client_header_timeout 3600;
    client_body_timeout 3600;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    proxy_connect_timeout 3600;

}
```

php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 3600
```

**Log error:**

```
2015/10/20 10:01:12 [error] 5132#0: *297705 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 195.215.168.170, server: xxxx.xx, request: "GET /cron/test HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "xxxx.xx"
```

Spent endless hours searching for solutions, but every solution I'v tried havn't had any effect. So any help is welcomed with open arms!

Comment: what is the value of `max_execution_time` in your php.ini ?

Comment: Have you set set_time_limit ( int $seconds ) for PHP?

Comment: max_execution_time = 3600
Have not set set_time_limit

Comment: @JuniusRendel Not a duplicate, since the asnwer was fastcgi_read_timeout in that post, which if you read my post, I'v already tried.

Comment: yes, but did you try the other directives in the answer ?

Comment: is `request_terminate_timeout` set in  `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`?

Comment: request_terminate_timeout seems to do the trick. if you create an answer, ill accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By increasing the `request_terminate_timeout` value in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, I was able to get rid of the 502 Bad Gateway.

Thanks to @JuniusRendel for the solution.